# Search for locations with flutter_map

Tags: flutter, leaflet, openstreetmap, fluttermap

I am using the Flutter Package "flutter_map" (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) and have implemented a map into my flutter application.

Now I want to add a search box where I can search for places which will be then focused on the map. Is something like that already included in the flutter_map-Package? I could not find anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an external API to search for places. As long as you follow their terms of service and don't use them for auto completion, https://nominatim.org/ is a good one for this, and it's free + open source.

Then, you can use `flutter_map`'s `MapController()` to move the map to that latitude longitude returned from the API request.